# How to add a checkbox in a column in a table in Java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox, defaulttablemodel

i´m trying to put a checkbox in a column in my table...but i shows de boolean value, when i click over the cell, it shows the checkbox and sooner show the boolean value...

```
    public class Tabela {

    private JTable tabela;
    private JCheckBox checkbox;

    public Tabela(Object[][] linhas, String[] nomeColunas) {    
        this.tabela = new JTable();
        this.tabela.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(linhas, nomeColunas));
        this.checkbox = new JCheckBox();
        this.tabela.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        this.tabela.getColumn("Selecione").setCellEditor(
              new DefaultCellEditor(checkbox));    
    }

    public JTable getTabela() {    
        return tabela;    
    }    
}
```

So what´s wrong with my code?

I create seppareted my form, table and panel...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must override `getColumnClass(...)` and return `Boolean.class` for the column that should display the checkboxes. The data model will need to hold Boolean objects for that column as well.

Comment: @user2283439: There are many examples including on this site, including that I've made, that I can find with Google. You can too. Please have a look.

Comment: I did it, i create a class extend from AbstractTableModel, i found on example, and showed it to me, now i need to know how to handle to select the value of checkbox, so thanks

Comment: @user2283439: a TableModelListener can listen for changes to the data, and then respond to them.

Comment: i´ve tried something like this to show me the value when i click but didn´t show

 public Tabela() {

  this.tabela = new JTable(new modeloTabela());
  this.tabela.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {

   @Override
   public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {

    if (e.getColumn() == 0) {

     TableModel tableModel = tabela.getModel();
     Boolean value = (Boolean) tableModel.getValueAt(e.getFirstRow(), 0);
     System.out.println(value);

    }
   }
  });
  this.tabela.setFillsViewportHeight(true);